# Crystal Report Not Following Original row order from Dataset

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting

Good Day!
I need a help regarding my Crystal Report, the problem is that it is not following the original order of rows in the detail section from my Query

Example:

This is my query:

[image: My Query]

But here's the result in Crystal Report:

[image: Result in Crystal Report]

How do I make the Crystal Report follow the original order of Rows in my query?

Answer (score 1):

Are you grouping for something in the report ? On group expert select option on the field and choose "in original order"